# How to dynamically change the x-axis label in HighCharts?

Tags: highcharts

I have used the customevents to make the labels on the x-axis clickable. And If you click it (for example, click "[Sale]") there will be an alert.

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/dq8wbdeu/1/

```
$(function () {

$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        polar: true,
        type: 'line'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Budget vs spending',
        x: -80
    },

    pane: {
        size: '80%'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Sales', 'Marketing', 'Development', 'Customer Support',
                'Information Technology', 'Administration'],
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        lineWidth: 0,
        labels:{
        formatter:function(){return '['+this.value+']'},
          events:{
              click:function(){alert(this)}
          }
        }
    },

    yAxis: {
        gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
        lineWidth: 0,
        min: 0
    },

    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>${point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>'
    },

    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 70,
        layout: 'vertical'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Allocated Budget',
        data: [43000, 19000, 60000, 35000, 17000, 10000],
        pointPlacement: 'on'
    }, {
        name: 'Actual Spending',
        data: [50000, 39000, 42000, 31000, 26000, 14000],
        pointPlacement: 'on'
    }]

});
});
```

I hope the lable "[Sale]" to become red after clicking, is that possible? How can I achieve that? I tried `this.style.color='red'` but failed. And since "this" in the function block is a bit weird, I don't know what should I do now.

Thanks!

Comment: You may use jQuery and css() in your case. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/dq8wbdeu/3/

Comment: Thanks, it looks great. Just wondering, what exactly is `this.element` for? Is there any documents for this? Is it part of HighChart or just HTML standards?

Comment: Here you may find information about this parameter http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Element